# OpenCV C++ code runs fine in terminal but error in running from eclipse - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to run C++ OpenCV programs in Eclipse IDE on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. They run fine when I use the terminal, as shown here-https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV.

But when I build the same code in Eclipse, I get the following error

**Error description-**

> opengl support available 
>   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/akash/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.7/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 269
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/akash/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.7/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

---

**My code is**

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    Mat img=imread("image.jpg");
    namedWindow("win",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("win",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 1;

}
```

I have taken care of the following-

1. kept the image.jpg in src and all other folders of the project.
2. double-checked the library names in /usr/local/lib
3. Added only a single include path for OpenCV header files.

I still cant seem to run it.

Please help.

Comment: and those header files are as follows-
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still think your problem comes from the program not finding the *image.jpg* file (even if you have taken a number of steps to make sure it does). The working directory - that an application is executed from - is often different from that of the source or binary folders in eclipse (you can actually set it manually in project settings).

To quickly verify this hypothesis you could pass the absolute path of *image.jpg* to `imread()`. If that solves the problem you just need to configure your working directory correctly in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, that rectified it. I went into the resource settings and found that it links just to the folder of the project, not the src folder, as I thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ filename.cpp -o outputfile-name pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

Ex:

Compilation:-

```
thinkpadt61@thinkpadt61-ThinkPad-T61:~/Kannathasan$ g++ simple.cpp -o sample pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

Run:

```
thinkpadt61@thinkpadt61-ThinkPad-T61: ./sample
```

Thats it!... Enjoy